# cmake -g flag not generating 'DWARF with dSym file' debug information

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I'm using cmake to generate a C++ Xcode project, but the debug information never gets generated. I have to manually select 'DWARF with dSym file' from the build setting every time I have generated the project with cmake.

Using 'SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")' makes no difference.

I'm also pretty sure it used to work correctly with XCode 6 (now using Xcode 7)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Solution

You can use [CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_an-attribute.html) variable.

To set `DWARF` you can use:

```
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf")
```

To set `DWARF with dSYM File`:

```
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf-with-dsym")
```

#### Hints

Name of the Xcode attribute and values can be found in "Quick Help" section (see square brackered `[DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT]`, `[dwarf]` and `[dwarf-with-dsym]`):

[image]

Comment: double thanks, I fixed some other naggling settings as well :-)

Comment: Note that using 'SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")' is still required together with setting CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT

Comment: Also note that best practices these days dictate to set properties directly on the target. In this case it would be done like so, without the CMAKE prefix: set_target_properties(${TARGETNAME} PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf-with-dsym")

Comment: this only works if Xcode generator is used, no? With Ninja + Clang it does not work for me

Comment: @IceFire I'd like to know that too.  I _could_ use Xcode to build for macOS, but I'd rather use Ninja on all platforms if possible.

Comment: @trojanfoe I managed to get it done. I think, you need to pass -g compiler flag in. Later, I use dsymutil to then extract the debug information from the executable because it's in there but not generated. Note that tools like macdeployqt trim debug symbols from the executable later, which is fine, as long as dSYM is already generated. Helpful? Maybe try out and ping me later

Comment: @IceFire I switched to the `Xcode` generator in the end as I didn't relish creating the `.dSYM` _files_ myself.  Thanks for the update though!